# Pytest / Django: How to change a decorator that is defined during build time?

Tags: django, testing, pytest, python-decorators

I am making a network request and give it a 10 second timeout.
The timeout is raised by a decorator that reads the time limit from `settings`, so it looks like this:

`@timeout(settings.TIMEOUT)`.

The problem is that I want the test to be super fast, so I change the timeout to `0.1`:

`settings.TIMEOUT = 0.1`

The problem is that the decorator is already `initialized` (I might be using the wrong word) by the time I try to test it. So the decorator is created/defined at build time, then I change the settings, but too late, the decorator doesn't read the updated setting again.

Here is a simplified version:

```
##############
settings.py
###############

TIMEOUT = 10
```

```
###############
request_maker.py
###############

from timeout_decorator import timeout
from django.conf import settings
from time import sleep

class MakeRequest

    @timeout(settings.TIMEOUT)
    def make_the_request(self):
        sleep(100)
```

```
###############
tests.py
###############

import pytest
from timeout_decorator import TimeoutError
from request_maker import MakeRequest


def test_make_request(settings):
    
    settings.TIMEOUT = 0.1

    mr = MakeRequest()

    with pytest.raises(TimeoutError) as e:
        mr.make_the_request()   # < Even though TIMEOUT is 0.1, it actually times out for 10 seconds
```

How can I change the code so that during production, it is `@timeout(10)` and during testing it is `@timeout(0.1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the `DEBUG` variable in your `settings.py` and assume that you initialize this variable from `.env` to determine if its production or not. Then you can initialize the `TIMEOUT` variable in `settings.py` depending on `DEBUG` variable like this:

```
DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG") == "True"
TIMEOUT = 0.1 if DEBUG else 10
```

Comment: This is simple and makes perfect sense, thanks!

Comment: @user1367204 did that solved your issue?

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak, yes it did!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I did 2 things:

1. I changed the way the module is loaded:

```
import request_maker
```

2. I reloaded the module after I updated the settings

```
settings.TIMEOUT = 0.1
reload(request_maker)
```

Here is the full new code:

```
###############
tests.py
###############

import pytest
from timeout_decorator import TimeoutError
import request_maker
from importlib import reload


def test_make_request(settings):
    
    settings.TIMEOUT = 0.1
    reload(request_maker)

    mr = request_maker.MakeRequest()

    with pytest.raises(TimeoutError) as e:
        mr.make_the_request()   # < Sleeps for 0.1 seconds only!
```